# How to merge files depending on a string in a specific column

Tags: bash, shell

I have two files that I need to merge together based on what string they contain in a specific column.

File 1 looks like this:

```
1 1655 1552 189  
1 1433 1552 185  
1 1623 1553 175  
1 691 1554 182  
1 1770 1554 184  
1 1923 1554 182  
1 1336 1554 181  
1 660 1592 179  
1 743 1597 179
```

File 2 looks like this:

```
1 1552 0 0 2 -9 G A A A  
1 1553 0 0 2 -9 A A G A  
1 1554 0 751 2 -9 A A A A  
1 1592 0 577 1 -9 G A A A  
1 1597 0 749 2 -9 A A G A  
1 1598 0 420 1 -9 A A A A  
1 1600 0 0 1 -9 A A G G  
1 1604 0 1583 1 -9 A A A A  
1 1605 0 1080 2 -9 G A A A
```

I am wanting to match column 3 from file 1 to column 2 on file 2, with my output looking like:

```
1 1655 1552 189 0 0 2 -9 G A A A  
1 1433 1552 185 0 0 2 -9 G A A A  
1 1623 1553 175 0 0 2 -9 A A G A  
1 691 1554 182 0 751 2 -9 A A A A  
1 1770 1554 184 0 751 2 -9 A A A A  
1 1923 1554 182 0 751 2 -9 A A A A  
1 1336 1554 181 0 751 2 -9 A A A A  
1 660 1592 179 0 577 1 -9 G A A A  
1 743 1597 179 0 749 2 -9 A A G A
```

I am not interested in keeping any lines in file 2 that are not in file 1. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Look at the [`join`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/join) utility.

Comment: Welcome to SO, please do add your efforts in form of code in your question, which is highly encouraged on SO.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @Abelisto I managed to figure something out 4 hours later!

```
sort -k 3,3 File1.txt > Pheno1.txt
awk '($2 >0)' File2.ped > Ped1.ped
sort -k 2,2 Ped1.ped > Ped2.ped
join -1 3 -2 2 Pheno1.txt Ped2.ped > Ped3.txt
cut -d ' ' -f 1,4,5 --complement Ped3.txt > Output.ped
```

My real File2 actually contained negative values in the 2nd column (thankfully my real File1 didn't have any negatives) hence the use of awk to remove those rows

Comment: Several  notes: 1) `<(command)` could be used as regular file, for example `cat <(echo foo)` It allows to avoid to create intermediate files 2) `/dev/shm` (shared memory) is available for intermediate files. It is much faster then regular storage devices. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Using awk:

```
awk 'NR == FNR { arr[$2]=$3" "$4" "$5" "$6" "$7" "$8" "$9" "$10 } NR != FNR { print $1" "$2" "$3" "$4" "arr[$3] }' file2 file1
```

Process file2 first (NR==FNR) Set up an array called arr with the 3rd space delimited field as the index and the 3rd to 10th fields as values separated with a space. Then when processing the first file (NR!=FNR) print the 1st to the 4th space delimited fields followed by the contents of arr, index field 3.

Comment: this assumes all lines in `file1` have a match in `file2`; add `1 743 9999 179` to `file1` (no match in `file2`) and your `awk` will display this line (from `file1`)

Comment: Thanks for the response - unfortunately my real File 2 has almost 800,000 columns so manually listing each column would take me quite some time

Answer (score 0):

Since `$1` seems like constant 1 and I have no idea about rowcounts of either file (800,000 columns in file2 sounded a lot) I'm hashing file1 instead:

```
$ awk '
NR==FNR {
    a[$3]=a[$3] (a[$3]==""?"":ORS) $2 OFS $3 OFS $4
    next
}
($2 in a) {
    n=split(a[$2],t,ORS)
    for(i=1;i<=n;i++) {
        $2=t[i]
        print
    }
}' file1 file2
```

Output:

```
1 1655 1552 189 0 0 2 -9 G A A A
1 1433 1552 185 0 0 2 -9 G A A A
1 1623 1553 175 0 0 2 -9 A A G A
1 691 1554 182 0 751 2 -9 A A A A
1 1770 1554 184 0 751 2 -9 A A A A
1 1923 1554 182 0 751 2 -9 A A A A
1 1336 1554 181 0 751 2 -9 A A A A
1 660 1592 179 0 577 1 -9 G A A A
1 743 1597 179 0 749 2 -9 A A G A
```

When posting a question, please add details such as row and column counts to it. Better requirements yield better answers.